# page opening in solution explorer instead of main tab in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Before when I double-clicked an item in Solution Explorer (VS 2013), it would open it in the main tab (I don't know if this is the name, but I hope you got the idea of what I'm referring to). Now, for some reason, it opens inside the Solution Explorer and I have to drag it to the "main" tab. Is there a way to restore to the original way it was before?

**UPDATE**

I just realized what is happening. Double clicking the document opens it in the main tab, as usual, however, if the app is running in the browser, double-clicking will open it in the Solution Explore window. I think this is the normal behavior and now I understand it.

Comment: Working fine for me in VS 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for what I found so far, the options available other than dragging is to right click in the page and choose the option that says: "Move to Main Document Group" or "Move to Previous Tab Group" if the former is not available.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the Solution Explorer window title and select the Dock command.